# Add a column to a table from a file with no matching columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a `scores` table like this:

```
> PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(SCORES);

0|GROUP_ID|TEXT|0||0
1|GROUP_INDEX|INTEGER|0||0
2|SCORE|REAL|0||0

+----------+-------------+-------+
| GROUP_ID | GROUP_INDEX | SCORE |
+----------+-------------+-------+
|   LJ1342 |           1 |  10.3 |
|   RX4351 |           2 |  14.7 |
+----------+-------------+-------+
```

where each `score` is unique to a `(group_id, group_index)`.

I have now recalculated the scores, and saved them to a csv file that looks like this:

```
(new_scores.csv)
,score
,7
,21
,3
```

i.e. without storing any info on `group_id` and `group_index`. (But I know that the each line in the CSV matches the corresponding record in the `scores` table, in the order that I appended them.)

I would now like to update the `score` column with the values in the file. But it has proven harder than I thought since there are no matching indices. (It is also a large table (80M rows) with some other long text columns so writing and erasing take quite some time.)

I tried to import my table, add an auto-incrementing column from 1..N for the N rows, and then add this to the `scores` table as well and join on this.

```
> .mode csv
> .import new_scores.csv
> insert into scores select score from new_scores;
```

This took a long time to write, and resulted in a `new_scores` column which was only blank strings.

Comment: i have no idea what you try to do, maybe a create table with data and wanted result a [mre] would help

Comment: I've edited to add some more info - I don't remember the exact commands I did

Comment: so oyu want to import a csv with ine 1 column, and that should be imported into the the table, how do  oyu gnerate groupid and index, you must undertand that the csv should have all three column idealy

Comment: Records in a relational table have no intrinsic order, so your statement “matches the corresponding record in the scores table, in the order that I appended them” is meaningless. Your database doesn’t “know” which order you appended records unless you supply the order as part of your update statement

Comment: @NickW aha, so that was what I hadn't realised. I have read about the ROWID column, can that not work as as index for joining?

Comment: If you want to join tables using SQL then you should always do this explicitly via columns whose values you know and understand. I don’t know how SQLite implements/maintains rowid values but you would need to confirm that it meets your requirements before you use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't defined one of the columns as an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then Sqlite will add a hidden `ROWID` column in every table.
`ROWID` is an auto incremented integer so, if you inserted the data and never deleted rows, you shouldn't have any gap.
You can check this with:

```
SELECT count(*) as num_records, min(rowid) as first, max(rowid) as last 
FROM scores;
```

If `first = 1` and `last = num_records` then every row has a numeric identifier, in the order you have inserted the rows, without gaps.

You should do the same check with the table `new_scores` you imported, to verify that both have the same numbers:

```
SELECT count(*) as num_records, min(rowid) as first, max(rowid) as last 
FROM new_scores;
```

If the above is true, you can then update the first table with:

```
UPDATE scores
SET score = new_scores.score
FROM new_scores
WHERE score.rowid = new_scores.rowid;
```